# Kafka Connect: MySQLDataException: outside valid range for the datatype BIGINT

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I try to create source to sync database mysql to mysql. But Kafka Connect produce this error:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLDataException: '13645356371071579777' in column '1' is outside valid range for the datatype BIGINT.
```

Kafka Connect Source Configuration:

```
name=source-student-table
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://hostname/schema_name
dialect.name= MySqlDatabaseDialect
connection.user=user
connection.password=password
topic.prefix=student
query=SELECT id, created_at, updated_at, uuid FROM student
mode=timestamp+incrementing
timestamp.column.name=updated_at
incrementing.column.name=id
tasks.max=1
```

Here's the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `uuid` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add `numeric.mapping=best_fit` on the Kafka Source configuration.
For further reading, please follow this link:
[Confluent Docs](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/source-connector/source_config_options.html#database)